# Make Eclipse throw a warning when accessing instance methods without 'this.'

Tags: java, eclipse

Can I configure Eclipse such that it will warn me when I access a member method without 'this.'?

Through `Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Unqualified access to instance field` you can achieve this behaviour for instance fields, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent option for instance methods.

Comment: *but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent checkbox for instance methods.* I don't believe there is any way to do this.

Comment: Search for plugins like cheklist /PMD , they provide xml configuration you might get that.

Comment: As already said, not built-in (because it's very uncommon and because it would be boilerplate code), but there is a Checkstyle rule (you have to install the Checkstyle plug-in for that): http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#RequireThis